# Calculate matching percentage of 2 dataframes in python

Tags: python, pandas

When joining `df2` on `df1`, using `First_Name`, `Last_Name` and `Email`, how can I calculate the percentage of `df2` that can be matched to `df1`?

`df1:`

```
    First_Name  Last_Name   Email                     Value1
0   Aaron       Potter      aaronpotter@gmail.com     10
1   Bella       Granger     bellagranger@gmail.com    2
2   Ron         Black       black@hotmail.com         20
3   Harry       Weasley     harryweasley@hotmail.com  11
```

`df2`:

```
    First_Name  Last_Name   Email                     Value2
0   Aaron       Potter      aaronpotter@gmail.com     10
1   Ronald      Black       ronaldblack@hotmail.com   5
2   Bella       Granger     bellagranger@gmail.com    2
3   Harry       Weasley     tomriddle@hotmail.com     20
```

For example, percentage of match is 2 out of 4 in this case.

Comment: `len(df1.merge(df2,on = ['First_Name', 'Last_Name', 'Email']))/len(df1)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@anky has a great solution to the problem.   I will offer the `indicator` parameter in `merge` to visually see the matches.

```
df_out = df1.merge(df2, on = ['First_Name', 'Last_Name', 'Email'], 
          indicator='Matched', how='out')
df_out
```

Output:

```
  First_Name Last_Name                     Email  Value1  Value2     Matched
0      Aaron    Potter     aaronpotter@gmail.com    10.0    10.0        both
1      Bella   Granger    bellagranger@gmail.com     2.0     2.0        both
2        Ron     Black         black@hotmail.com    20.0     NaN   left_only
3      Harry   Weasley  harryweasley@hotmail.com    11.0     NaN   left_only
4     Ronald     Black   ronaldblack@hotmail.com     NaN     5.0  right_only
5      Harry   Weasley     tomriddle@hotmail.com     NaN    20.0  right_only
```

Or, left-join:

```
df_out = df1.merge(df2, on = ['First_Name', 'Last_Name', 'Email'], 
          indicator='Matched', how='left')
print(df_out)
```

Output:

```
  First_Name Last_Name                     Email  Value1  Value2    Matched
0      Aaron    Potter     aaronpotter@gmail.com      10    10.0       both
1      Bella   Granger    bellagranger@gmail.com       2     2.0       both
2        Ron     Black         black@hotmail.com      20     NaN  left_only
3      Harry   Weasley  harryweasley@hotmail.com      11     NaN  left_only
```

And using, @anky's solution:

```
(df_out['Matched'] == 'both').sum()/df_out.shape[0]
```

Output:

```
0.5
```

Answer (score 1):

@Scott Boston's answer is perfect! If you only have 'First_Name', 'Last_Name' and 'Email', you can use the following code.

```
df = pd.concat([df1[['First_Name','Last_Name','Email']],df2[['First_Name','Last_Name','Email']]])
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
gb = df.groupby(list(df.columns))
idx = [x[0] for x in gb.groups.values() if len(x) == 2]
df.reindex(idx)

    First_Name  Last_Name   Email
0   Aaron   Potter  aaronpotter@gmail.com
1   Bella   Granger bellagranger@gmail.com
```